# How to receive string at a time from server in client?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

in the java server part i am sending separate strings at once, but in the client part i am receiving all of them as if they are one string. how can i separate each string received.
here is my code.

client part:

```
uint8_t buf[1024];
unsigned int len = 0;
len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
NSString *s;

    NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];
    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSString *firstString;// save first string received here
     NSString *secondString;// save second string received here
     NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

server part:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket=new ServerSocket(6789);
while(true){
try{
Socket connectionSocket=welcomeSocket.accept();
OutputStream outToClient=new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
outToClient.write("sign up accepted you can now sign in\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
outToClient.write("enter\n".getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e)}
finally{
if(outToClient!=null){
outToClient.flush();
}
```

Comment: you could send a fixed number of bytes as a 'packet width' each time you write to the output stream on the server (Padding unused bytes with zeroes or something), then on the client side you read by filling a buffer with the same number of bytes. Or you could just send them all and delimit the strings with a sentinel character and not worry about it.

Comment: Make sure to call `outToClient.flush()` when you're done writing

Comment: One way would be to use a highly abstract class like `PrintWriter` to handle the writing part in the server(Java). So you would be writing sentences line-by-line, where newline would be the delimiter.

Comment: Are there no other simpler way that i can do on the client part that will retrieve each string one at a time? because i am used to java and in java this is done easily using a bufferedReader for example